# Code coverage with qemu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, arm, qemu

I recently started using qemu and it's a great tool when you don't have the required hardware to run your firmware (currently using it for cortex-m3).

Now what I want to do is to do some test coverage with it. I tried using GNUC ARM Eclipse, and I've been successfull compiling and executing the code in qemu, but whenever I add the -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage flags (for the project and then for the desired file to run coverage) I am able to create the .gcno file, which means that after executing my code it will generate a .gcda file and then I should be able to see the coverage.

Thtat's where everything goes wrong. I was able to generate a .gcda file but whenever I try to open any of them, eclipse tells me that it wasn't able to open the file because it was null. I've tried replicating the procedure in another computer, but I haven't been successful creating the gcda file (probably different binaries).

At this point I don't really know how to proceed. Should I abandon ARM Eclipse and stick to makefiles (is it possibll to run gcov this way?) or am I missing something really small that is fixable?

PS: I using windows 7 64 bits, the latest versions available on the GNU ARM Eclipse website. Also the idea of doing it via makefiles just occurred to me (it was a stresfull day, it's really late) so I haven't tried it yet, I've only tried executing the code, but without coverage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, qemu is not able to generate DWARF information. But there is a project with the proposal of code coverage with qemu: [Couverture Project](http://www.open-do.org/projects/couverture/)

Answer (score 0):

When you use qemu as a user space emulator (see also the [qemu documentation](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/user/main.html)) you actually can measure the code coverage as usual. In this mode qemu has the full access to the host file system.

For a CMake project you can simply use the [CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR.html) property of your test executable, e.g.:

```
if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    set_target_properties(mytest
        PROPERTIES
            CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR "qemu-${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR};-L;$ENV{SDKTARGETSYSROOT}"
    )
endif()
```

With this setting `ctest` will use qemu for running the test and will write the .gcda files to the usual location in your build directory.